# How to get get View Flipper Animation just like in GDocs for android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to get a animation as in the GDocs app for android. In this app when you select All Items, you can switch left or right to navigate between the starred, All Items and Owned by me. All the 3 of them are a list of documents.

Now when the user starts to touch the screen and slide the list moves the same size as much the touch is moved by the user on the screen. I mean if the touch is done for say 1 cm, the view moves by 1 cm to left or right based on the user swipe direction. Now when the user removes his hand from the screen, the view completes the flip. I mean if swiped left and when removed the hand the view flips to starred and if flipped right and immediately as the user removes the hand from screen view flips to the owned by me.

Can some one tell me how this kind of a animation is created in this GDocs app. I want to do a same animation in my application. Please let me know if there are any sample application that are doing such a animation which i can use. Thank you for all your help and time.